# display text of a link when focused using tab key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Code:

```html
<a href="#about"> About <abbr title="The Little Taco Shop">About LTS</abbr></a>
```

Display the text "About LTS" when we click on tab key in keyboard.

Comment: <a href="#about"></a>
              <abbr title="The Little Taco Shop">About LTS</abbr>
              </a>

Comment: Why isn't that text already visible, where's your relevant CSS (and/or JavaScript)? Where do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: This question needs more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

When the tab is focused on the link, the description tag becomes active. The description disappears when the focus is removed.

Did you want this?

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event)=> {
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {  
      document.getElementById("focusBtn").addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
        document.getElementById("alt").style.display = "inline-block";
      });
      document.getElementById("focusBtn").addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
        document.getElementById("alt").style.display = "none";
      });   
    }
});
```

```css
#alt{
  display:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#about" id="focusBtn" > About <abbr id="alt" title="The Little Taco Shop">About LTS</abbr></a>
```